# C++ solving for quartic roots (fourth order polynomial)

Tags: c++, math, polynomial-math, equation-solving

As part of my project I need to solve a quartic polynomial in a **closed form** in C++.

> A*x<sup>4</sup> + B*x<sup>3</sup> + C*x<sup>2</sup> + D*x + E = 0

I found several links to this end. One of them is [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/451048-best-way-of-solving-a-polynomial-of-the-fourth-degree/). But it computes all roots, while I want just real roots. The algorithms mainly use Ferrari's method to reduce the order.

```
bool solveQuartic(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double &root)
{
// I switched to this method, and it seems to be more numerically stable.
// http://www.gamedev.n...topic_id=451048 

// When a or (a and b) are magnitudes of order smaller than C,D,E
// just ignore them entirely. This seems to happen because of numerical
// inaccuracies of the line-circle algorithm. I wanted a robust solver,
// so I put the fix here instead of there.
if(a == 0.0 || abs(a/b) < 1.0e-5 || abs(a/c) < 1.0e-5 || abs(a/d) < 1.0e-5)
    return solveCubic(b, c, d, e, root);

double B = b/a, C = c/a, D = d/a, E = e/a;
double BB = B*B;
double I = -3.0*BB*0.125 + C;
double J = BB*B*0.125 - B*C*0.5 + D;
double K = -3*BB*BB/256.0 + C*BB/16.0 - B*D*0.25 + E;

double z;
bool foundRoot2 = false, foundRoot3 = false, foundRoot4 = false, foundRoot5 = false;
if(solveCubic(1.0, I+I, I*I - 4*K, -(J*J), z))
{
    double value = z*z*z + z*z*(I+I) + z*(I*I - 4*K) - J*J;

    double p = sqrt(z);
    double r = -p;
    double q = (I + z - J/p)*0.5;
    double s = (I + z + J/p)*0.5;

    bool foundRoot = false, foundARoot;
    double aRoot;
    foundRoot = solveQuadratic(1.0, p, q, root);
    root -= B/4.0;

    foundARoot = solveQuadratic(1.0, r, s, aRoot);
    aRoot -= B/4.0;
    if((foundRoot && foundARoot && ((aRoot < root && aRoot >= 0.0) 
        || root < 0.0)) || (!foundRoot && foundARoot)) 
    {
        root = aRoot;
        foundRoot = true;
    }

    foundARoot = solveQuadraticOther(1.0, p, q, aRoot);
    aRoot -= B/4.0;
    if((foundRoot && foundARoot && ((aRoot < root && aRoot >= 0.0) 
        || root < 0.0)) || (!foundRoot && foundARoot)) 
    {
        root = aRoot;
        foundRoot = true;
    }

    foundARoot = solveQuadraticOther(1.0, r, s, aRoot);
    aRoot -= B/4.0;
    if((foundRoot && foundARoot && ((aRoot < root && aRoot >= 0.0) 
        || root < 0.0)) || (!foundRoot && foundARoot)) 
    {
        root = aRoot;
        foundRoot = true;
    }
    return foundRoot;
}
return false;
}
```

This uses solveCubic() which gives both real and imaginary solution:

```
bool solveCubic(double &a, double &b, double &c, double &d, double &root)
{
if(a == 0.0 || abs(a/b) < 1.0e-6)
    return solveQuadratic(b, c, d, root);

double B = b/a, C = c/a, D = d/a;

double Q = (B*B - C*3.0)/9.0, QQQ = Q*Q*Q;
double R = (2.0*B*B*B - 9.0*B*C + 27.0*D)/54.0, RR = R*R;

// 3 real roots
if(RR<QQQ)
{
    /* This sqrt and division is safe, since RR >= 0, so QQQ > RR,    */
    /* so QQQ > 0.  The acos is also safe, since RR/QQQ < 1, and      */
    /* thus R/sqrt(QQQ) < 1.                                     */
    double theta = acos(R/sqrt(QQQ));
    /* This sqrt is safe, since QQQ >= 0, and thus Q >= 0             */
    double r1, r2, r3;
    r1 = r2 = r3 = -2.0*sqrt(Q);
    r1 *= cos(theta/3.0);
    r2 *= cos((theta+2*PI)/3.0);
    r3 *= cos((theta-2*PI)/3.0);

    r1 -= B/3.0;
    r2 -= B/3.0;
    r3 -= B/3.0; 

    root = 1000000.0;

    if(r1 >= 0.0) root = r1;
    if(r2 >= 0.0 && r2 < root) root = r2;
    if(r3 >= 0.0 && r3 < root) root = r3;

    return true;
}
// 1 real root
else
{
    double A2 = -pow(fabs®+sqrt(RR-QQQ),1.0/3.0);
    if (A2!=0.0) {
        if (R<0.0) A2 = -A2; 
        root = A2 + Q/A2; 
    }
    root -= B/3.0;
    return true;
}
}
```

Here are some links that explain the code. [solveCubic](http://www.1728.org/cubic2.htm) and [solveQuartic](http://www.1728.org/quartic2.htm)

Is there anyone who can modify the code to solve a quartic polynomial for real roots?

I want to implement it as efficiently as possible. BTW I'd appreciate if someone introduced a useful library for this purpose like LAPACK (it seems to be unable to calculate the roots of a quartic polynomial directly).

Comment: calculate all roots and then discard?

Comment: Are you looking for Numerical solutions or Symbolic solutions?

Comment: We don't "provide code". We help you understand errors in *your* code.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'm lookking for closed form(symbolic)

Comment: @alestanis I provided a code in the link: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/451048-best-way-of-solving-a-polynomial-of-the-fourth-degree/  Now I want to get real roots in an efficient way

Comment: Don't provide code in a link. Provide code here. We don't want to have to visit some external website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way to solve this equation in closed form for real roots is to solve it in closed form for all roots and then discard the roots which are imaginary.

You might think you could use try/catch pairs to determine if imaginary numbers are cropping up, but this isn't a very good strategy because some of the intermediate values you generate in calculating a real root may be imaginary.

Therefore, you could try using a C++ complex numbers library (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0040__Data-Types/0460__complex-number.htm)) to do the calculations.

Afterwards, check to see if the imaginary part of the number is non-zero and, if it is discard it. But remember, floating-point math is inexact, so "zero" includes a range of numbers which are very close to zero.